# SAP CAP Node.js OData query lambda operator with HANA Cloud Database

Tags: node.js, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-cap, sap-business-application-studio

I am working on SAP CAP Node.js project with Hana-cloud database, which is deployed to SAP BTP Cloud Foundry.

```
cds -v
@sap/cds: 7.3.0
@sap/cds-compiler: 4.3.0
@sap/cds-dk: 7.3.0
@sap/cds-dk (global): 7.3.0
@sap/cds-fiori: 1.1.0
@sap/cds-foss: 4.0.2
@sap/cds-mtxs: 1.12.1
@sap/eslint-plugin-cds: 2.6.3
Node.js: v18.14.2
```

CAP OData Service local response :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "$metadata#Books",
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": 17,
            "title": "CAP - what's new in 2023",
            "price": 29.99,
            "author_ID": 999,
        "email":[ "abc@yahoo.com", "def@gmail.com"]
        },
        {
            "ID": 85,
            "title": "CAP - New Features",
            "price": 39.99,
            "author_ID": 997,
        "email":[ "xyz@yahoo.com", "aaa@gmail.com", "bbb@hotmail.com"]
        },
        {
            "ID": 42,
            "title": "CAP - Debugging",
            "price": 59.99,
            "author_ID": 900,
        "email":[ "abc@yahoo.com", "xyz@gmail.com"]
        }
    ]
}
```

To test Lambda operator query on "email" array field locally, below queries are used.

```
###
# Test 1
GET http://localhost:4004/browse/Books?
  &$filter=email/any(d:d eq 'abc@yahoo.com')

###
# Test 2
GET http://localhost:4004/browse/Books?
  &$filter=email/all(d:d eq 'abc@yahoo.com')

###
# Test 3
GET http://localhost:4004/browse/Books?
  &$filter=label/any(r:contains(r,'abc'))

###
# Test 4
GET http://localhost:4004/browse/Books?
  &$filter=label/any(r:startswith(r,'abc'))
```

All the above local test gives the same response as shown below :
[image]

Have gone through several post on Lambda operator's in SAP CAP and found that lambda operator works fine with HANA unlike SQLite DB but as seen from above, it is not working for me.

Please guide.

Regards.